# Bit.ly / Ow.ly links passing Google +1 juice?

Tags: url-shortener

We've started posting our website articles to Google+ via Hootsuite, and the result of this is that the links to the pages are shortened via Ow.ly.

Now on our Google+ page, we're noticing that even though the posted pages have been +1'd a number of times, the counter on the actual web page isn't incrementing.

Previously when we posted direct to the Google+ page the counter would increment.

Are we therefore losing any +1 goodness by using Hootsuite?

Cheers,

Chris.

Comment: This really isn't a question for SO, but to answer your question: +1 (and facebook likes too, I believe) are based on a url, even if it redirects somewhere else. So, yes, your +1's are wasted on the shortened links and won't be applied to the redirected url.

Comment: I struggled to find the correct place to post it, as it seems like there's a myriad of different StackExchange sites now. Bit over confusing. Thanks for your answer though - yes thats what I thought. I will contact Hootsuite directly and see if there's a way not to shorten the links.